# Liferay portlet direct URL?

Tags: url, liferay, portlet

Is it possible to query portlet interior directly from web browser? Which URL I should use given a portlet name and web application name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the whole point of portlets is to not generate standalone pages.

What you can do is make a page in liferay with your portlet occupying the whole page (which means apropriate theme and layout template) and pass a link to that.

Note that 'MAXIMIZED' portlet state will only maximize it to fill the portlet area in the theme, so you'll need a 'full screen' theme anyway.

Comment: There is also the EXCLUSIVE mode which can be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Like Julien Lafont hinted in another comment, Liferay adds two window states:

- Exclusive (`LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE`)
- Popup (`LiferayWindowState.POP_UP`)

`Exclusive` only outputs the portlet content, without any decoration, and without any proper html/js/css surroundings. It's useful for embedding in a DOM with those surroundings.

`Popup` outputs the portlet content, surrounded by all html/js/css to properly display the portlet. Used to display portlets in a popup (iframe) for example.